# raspberry pi email listening

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi that I connected a webcam to and am planning to use as a cctv camera ( I used this tutorial by the way: https://medium.com/p/2d5a2d61da3d) and I want it to send me an email when it takes a picture, how can I do this, I don't know much about python or linux, help is appreciated.

Comment: These are two separate questions - you may wish to split them. Check out http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html for email examples.

Comment: This is a kind of open-ended question that's not well-suited for Stack Overflow, but if you want some starting points take a look at [SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/) which is a nice, easy Python library that will do pretty much everything you need on the webcam/motion-detection front and should work on your RasPi.  Look into Python's e-mail modules for sending multi-part formatting e-mails with attachments; there are many guides out there to doing this.  SimpleCV also has its own Stack Overflow-style Q&A site too so you might want to ask for help over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the following:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=45235

This saves the image, rather than emailing it, so it will require some tweaking. Look through the code, understand as much as you can, and if you have a SPECIFIC question ("what does this one line do?") and google doesn't show anything, then you can post here again.